# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: list position for Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I have a Windows Form which contains 2 data grid views which represent a 1:n relationship. When the user clicks on a row from the parent table (corresponding to the first data grid view), then the tuples from the child table related to that row appear in the second data grid view.

The problem is that when I'm interacting with the form and clicking inside the data grid views, the program crashes with this output:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: list position
  at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Current () [0x0001c] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit () [0x0000a] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.set_Position (System.Int32 value) [0x00037] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.UpdateBindingPosition (System.Int32 position) [0x0000e] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore (System.Int32 columnIndex, System.Int32 rowIndex, System.Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, System.Boolean validateCurrentCell, System.Boolean throughMouseClick) [0x001c7] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.MoveCurrentCell (System.Int32 x, System.Int32 y, System.Boolean select, System.Boolean isControl, System.Boolean isShift, System.Boolean scroll) [0x00105] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnListPositionChanged (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs args) [0x0004c] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ResetRows () [0x0005d] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnListChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs args) [0x0004d] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnListChanged (System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs args) [0x00008] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ListChangedHandler (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) [0x0003d] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnListChanged (System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) [0x00019] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetBindings (System.Boolean metadataChanged) [0x0000b] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.SetList (System.Collections.IList l) [0x000b8] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetList () [0x00112] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnParentCurrencyManagerChanged (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs args) [0x00006] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void_object_EventArgs(object,System.EventArgs)
  at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnCurrentChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x0001d] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.set_Position (System.Int32 value) [0x00044] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.UpdateBindingPosition (System.Int32 position) [0x0000e] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore (System.Int32 columnIndex, System.Int32 rowIndex, System.Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, System.Boolean validateCurrentCell, System.Boolean throughMouseClick) [0x001c7] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDown (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) [0x0014e] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmLButtonDown (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x0008b] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x001bc] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x0000b] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (System.IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Msg msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) [0x00085] in <6d635ac3dc1c4424ad385ded79f1e868>:0
```

Can you explain me what is happening/what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Here is the relevant source code, I guess (there's also the automatically generated *Form1.Designer.cs* file but I believe that the problem isn't there):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace A1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection;
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapterPosition, dataAdapterSalary;
        DataSet dataSet;
        SqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilderSalary;
        BindingSource bindingSourcePosition, bindingSourceSalary;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var connectionString = Program.getConnectionString();
            if (connectionString == null)
            {
                Program.LogError("[error][Form1.button1_Click()] connectionString is null after reading it from file. ");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("[log][Form1.button1_Click()] connectionString: " + connectionString);
            if ((sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) == null)
            {
                Program.LogError("[error][Form1.button1_Click()] creating a SQL Connection failed");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("[log][Form1.button1_Click()] created SQL Connection");
            
            try
            {
                // open the connection
                sqlConnection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("[log][Form1.button1_Click()] Opened the SQL Connection");
                Console.WriteLine("[log][Form1.button1_Click()] The state of the connection: " + sqlConnection.State);

                // switch to the CoffeeShopDB
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("USE [CoffeeShopDB]", sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("[log][Form1.button1_Click()] Switched to [CoffeeShopDB]");
                }


                dataAdapterPosition = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Position", sqlConnection);
                dataAdapterSalary = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Salary", sqlConnection);
                sqlCommandBuilderSalary = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapterSalary);
                
                dataSet = new DataSet();
                dataAdapterPosition.Fill(dataSet, "Position");
                dataAdapterSalary.Fill(dataSet, "Salary");

                dataSet.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("FK_pid_Position_to_Salary", dataSet.Tables["Position"].Columns["pid"], dataSet.Tables["Salary"].Columns["pidfk"]));

                bindingSourcePosition = new BindingSource { DataSource = dataSet, DataMember = "Position" };
                bindingSourceSalary = new BindingSource { DataSource = bindingSourcePosition, DataMember = "FK_pid_Position_to_Salary" };

                dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSourcePosition;
                dataGridView2.DataSource = bindingSourceSalary;


                // END: free resources
                //sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataSet != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[log][Form1.button2_Click()] Updated " + dataAdapterSalary.Update(dataSet, "Salary") + " rows");
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Program.LogError("[error][Form1.button2_Click()] Exception caught: " + exception.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Program.LogError("[error][Form1.button2_Click()] dataSet is null");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: here are the generated files:

1. [Form1.Designer.cs](https://pastebin.com/dwm19jjw)
2. [CoffeeShopDBDataSet.Designer.cs](https://pastebin.com/tt4aAjtH)

I tried wrapping `Application.Run(new Form1());` in a try-catch block, but to no avail. The exception isn't caught.

EDIT 2:
I get only get this behaviour on Linux (Ubuntu), in both Rider and MonoDevelop. On Windows everything works fine.

Comment: From what you state… _”The problem is that when I'm interacting with the form and clicking inside the data grid views, the program crashes with this output:…”_ … this sounds like some grid event is causing this issue. What event(s) is each grid subscribed to? I do not really see anything in the posted code that would throw this error. Typically, when this error is thrown the IDE will give you some idea of which line of code threw the error… what line of code throws the exception?

Comment: I provided the the output of the crash in the post, but, as you can see, there's no reference to a line of my code. That's why I don't get where the problem is. My guess is that it something to do with the binding between the DataGridView.DataSource and the BindingSource or the DataSet. I also provided the generated code in the post, if that helps.

Comment: Where is `CoffeeShopDBDataSet` defined?

Comment: @JohnG, I provided it now in the post.

Comment: In my small tests, if you are getting back valid tables from the query, then the way the code is setting up the `DataSet` tables and relation appears correct. Also, the way the code sets up the binding sources using the tables from the data set also appears correct. I made a mock setup and used your posted code and it worked as expected without errors in the grids in a master-detail scenario. So… I am not sure if I agree with your assumption… _”that it something to do with the binding between the DataGridView.DataSource and the BindingSource or the DataSet.”_ …

Comment: Something else appears to be going on. Have you commented out all the binding code and relations and simply set the data source for the grids to the tables and see if you get the same error? This would certainly eliminate or confirm your guess as to the problem?

Comment: I tried setting the DataSource of the 2 DataGridViews directly to the DataSet with their respective DataMembers , but I still get a weird behaviour where, sometimes, when clicking on an empty row, mutiple others appear below. And when I try to the delete the last row, then the program crashes with https://pastebin.com/rDuHNTcZ.